# Django queryset values to be altered and sent to user in plain txt copy

Tags: django, text

This is my code able to sent plain text file to user with all queryset results but requirement is alignment of results by removing symbols.

```
def save_search(request,q="deve"):
   filename = "mytext.txt"
   content =Buildkb.objects.values("text","knowledge","created_by_email").
               filter(Q(knowledge__icontains=q)|Q(text__icontains=q))
   response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename{0}'.format(filename)
return response
```

output:-

```
 {'knowledge': 'Deve Category.', 'created_by_email': 'user1@gmail.com', 'text': 'Deve'}{'knowledge': 'Software development life cycle (SDLC) is a series of phases that provide a common understanding of the software building process. How the software will be realized and developed from the business understanding and requirements elicitation phase to convert these business ideas and requirements into functions and features until its usage and operation to achieve the business needs. The good software engineer should have enough knowledge on how to choose the SDLC model based on the project context and the business requirement.', 'created_by_email': 'user3@gmail.com', 'text': '1.1'}{'knowledge': 'Software development life cycle (SDLC) is a series of phases that provide a common understanding of the software building process. How the software will be realised and developed from the business understanding and requirements elicitation phase to convert these business ideas and requirements into functions and features until its usage and operation to achieve the business needs. The good software engineer should have enough knowledge on how to choose the SDLC model based on the project context and the business requirements.\n\n', 'created_by_email': 'user3@gmail.com', 'text': 'dev'}{'knowledge': ' the department develops applications http://192.168.1.200:2000/buildknowledge/', 'created_by_email': 'prakash.mutalik@gmail.com', 'text': 'development'}{'knowledge': 'Java is a general-purpose computer-programming language that is concurrent, class-based, object-oriented, and specifically designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible. It is intended to let application developers "write once, run anywhere" (WORA),meaning that compiled Java code can run on all platforms that support Java without the need for recompilation.\n\nJava applications are typically compiled to bytecode that can run on any Java virtual machine (JVM) regardless of computer architecture. As of 2016, Java is one of the most popular programming languages in use, particularly for client-server web applications, with a reported 9 million developers.Java was originally developed by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems (which has since been acquired by Oracle Corporation) and released in 1995 as a core component of Sun Microsystems\' Java platform. The language derives much of its syntax from C and C  , but it has fewer low-level facilities than either of them.', 'created_by_email': 'user3@gmail.com', 'text': 'java'}
```

Requirement:-

```
knowledge: Deve Category.
created_by_email:'user1@gmail.com'
text: Deve

knowledge: Software development life cycle (SDLC) is a series of phases that 
provide a common understanding of the software building process. How the 
software will be realized and developed from the business understanding and 
requirements elicitation phase to convert these business ideas and 
requirements into functions and features until its usage and operation to 
achieve the business needs. The good software engineer should have enough 
knowledge on how to choose the SDLC model based on the project context and 
the business requirement. 
created_by_email: 'user3@gmail.com'
text: 1.1

knowledge: Software development life cycle (SDLC) is a series of phases 
that provide a common understanding of the software building process. How 
the software will be realised and developed from the business understanding 
and requirements elicitation phase to convert these business ideas and 
requirements into functions and features until its usage and operation to 
achieve the business needs. The good software engineer should have enough 
knowledge on how to choose the SDLC model based on the project context and 
the business requirements.\n\n
created_by_email: 'user3@gmail.com'
text: dev

knowledge: the department develops applications
http://192.168.1.200:2000/buildknowledge/', 
created_by_email: 'user4@gmail.com'
text: 'development'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple renders available in REST framework. In case you want to have plain/text response, create a custom renderer.

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from rest_framework import renderers


class PlainTextRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'text/plain'
    format = 'txt'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        <<Write your custom code here>>
        return data.encode(self.charset)
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers

Answer (score 0):

Jitendra's answer is the correct answer, but bear in mind an alternative is to use render() to render a template that receives your 'content' as the 'context'.

You can then do your formatting within the template and this may allow you greater flexibility in formatting your output to look good on the rendered page.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/